# How to zoom out/scale page to 90% with css

Tags: html, css, scale

I am having trouble with my website here https://www.customlogoshop.com

When I use a device like a laptop, it is too zoomed in and when I zoom out to 90% it looks so much better.

I used zoom:90%; first, but this does not work for Firefox or safari. With some research I found that transform:scale (0.9); is the way to go.

However when I do this like this

html or body {transform:scale(0.9); it makes the website have massive gaps on all around it. Can't figure out how to just get it like the zoom out css I first did.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use media queries or percentage widths to make your layout work without zoom.

Comment: All websites should look the same in terms of zoom and scale, as long as your document has the viewport meta tag in its head: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. You might see your website scale differently on your PC and on your laptop because of the pixel density differences between the two screens. So the correct approach to this is to make your website responsive with `@media` queries!

Comment: It works. I just think zoomed out looks much better on the laptop.

Comment: If I can simply zoom out to 90% for the whole webpage, it will make it much easier as I don't have the time to tweak the whole website

Comment: Anyone find a solution?

Comment: @LukeHall this is exactly what we need for our project as well. Were you able to find anything?